# What is the complexity of computing a compatible 3-coloring of a complete graph?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-theory

Given a complete graph whose edges are colored by 3 colors, *a compatible 3-coloring* is a coloring of nodes such that no edge of the graph has the same color as its end-points.

The best algorithm I know is quasi-polynomial time. The problem is not known to be NP-complete. What is known about the status of this problem ?

Comment: Hi turkistany
  it would be very helpful if you were to provide more context for your questions, and this one in general. Specifically, what's a 'compatible' 3-coloring, and what's the history of the problem that you're already aware of ?

Comment: The phrase "no edge of the graph has the same color as its end-points" might be somewhat ambiguous. What is meant is that for each edge, at least one of its endpoints has a different color than the edge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, this paper by Cygan, Pilipczuk, Pilipczuk and Wojtaszczyk (2010+) gives a faster (polynomial time) algorithm: http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.5010

It was accepted to SODA 2011.

Answer (score 5):

The fastest known algorithm has running time $n^{O(\log n/ \log \log n)}$ [1].
Your question is reposed as an open problem in [2, page 4].

[1]: T. Feder, P. Hell, D. Král, and J. Sgall. Two algorithms for general list matrix partitions. SODA 2005, pages 870–876.

[2]: E. D. Demaine, M. Hajiaghayi, D. Marx. Open Problems -- Parameterized complexity and approximation algorithms. Dagstuhl Seminar 09511 (2009). Available [here](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2010/2499/).